# Javascript function not working inside php code

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call a javascript function inside a php code with for loop. But its not working. I guess that there is something wrong in the line where I have called the function. Please suggest how to edit the code so that the javascript function can work properly. This is the code I have tried.

```
<?php
?>
<script>

function calculate(aa, mad, hs, gra, mas, nsm, phd, exp, intv){

document.getElementById(aa).value=document.getElementById(mad).value/10 -(-     document.getElementById(hs).value/10)-(-document.getElementById(gra).value/5)-(-document.getElementById(mas).value/5)-(-document.getElementById(nsm).value)-(-document.getElementById(phd).value)-(-document.getElementById(exp).value)-(-document.getElementById(intv).value);
}

</script>

<?php
echo "
<form action='gl1p.php' method='post'>";


$noc=20;




echo "

<table align='center' border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse'    align='center'><tr>
<th>Sl. No</th><th>Name</th><th>Caste</th><th>Madhyamik</th><th>HS</th>   <th>Graduation</th><th>Masters</th><th>NET/SLET/MPhil</th><th>PhD</th> <th>Experience</th><th>Interview</th><th>Calculate</th><th>Score</th>

</tr>";

for ($i=1;$i<=$noc;++$i){



echo "<tr><td align='center'></td><td align='center' ><input type='text'   size='45' id='name{$i}' name='name[$i]'></td><td><select id='caste{$i}' name='caste[$i]'><option></option><option>UR</option><option>SC</option><option>ST</option><option>OBC</option></select></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='mad{$i}' name='mad[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input    type='text' size='1' id='hs{$i}' name='hs[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='gra{$i}' name='gra[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='mas{$i}' name='mas[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='nsm{$i}' name='nsm[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='phd{$i}' name='phd[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='exp{$i}' name='exp[$i]'></td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='intv{$i}' name='intv[$i]'></td><td><input type=Button value=Calculate onclick=calculate('tot'.$i, 'mad'.$i, 'hs'.$i, 'gra'.$i, 'mas'.$i, 'nsm'.$i, 'phd'.$i, 'exp'.$i, 'intv'.$i)>";//
echo "</td><td align='center'><input type='text' size='1' id='tot{$i}'  name='tot[$i]'></td></tr>";
}



echo "
</table>
<br/><br/><br/>

<div align='center'><input type='submit' value='Prepare merit list' ></div>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I see you are doing this: calculate('tot'.$i, 'mad'.$i, 'hs'.$i, 'gra'.$i, 'mas'.$i, 'nsm'.$i, 'phd'.$i, 'exp'.$i, 'intv'.$i) . Is that OK? Do you really want to call the function with those parameters? calculate("'tot'.1", "'mad'.1" ....) for example?

Comment: You're function isn't being called because it isn't quoted properly.  I'd **highly** advise you to make a strong effort to clean up the code... spacing, quoting, naming, etc. it will make it much easier to debug.

Comment: code shown is a mess. Keep your javascript separate from php

Comment: @Mindastic                                                                                    Actually I want to change the ids for each loop and use these ids as the function arguments. For example I want to set the ids as mad1, hs1,.... for for i=1 and use the function as calculate (..,'mad1', 'hs1',...). Then mad2, hs2,.... for for i=2 and use the function as calculate (..,'mad2', 'hs2',...).

Comment: In that case, you are concatenating it wrong. You don't need to add the single quotes there since you are wrapping the entire string in double quotes and that will take $i as variables. If you want to be double sure the variables are being taken into account OK, you can wrap them in curly braces {$i}.
Check the button code carefully, you are writing id, name and value without properly quoting it.
Also, you would need to clean your code, IT IS A MESS!.

Comment: I have tried calculate(..,'mad{$i}', 'hs{$i}',...), calculate(..,'mad[$i]', 'hs[$i]',...) etc. What should be the proper syntex?

Answer (score -1):

you can call it like this

```
<?php
  echo '
    <script>
      yourFunction(2,1,33);
    </script>
  ';
?>
```